# "Remind" vs. "Remember"

Tags: word-choice

> 1. With many thanks for your kind letter, and with a request that you ***remember me*** to your old colleagues while we were in ...
> 2. With many thanks for your kind letter, and with arequest that you ***remind me*** to your old colleagues while we were in ...

1 is correct because is the original version (The New York Times), but is there some suggestion to correctly use "remind" and "remember"? Please explain in reference to the cases above.

Comment: Without the complete sentence, they both appear wrong to me.

Comment: @DreamEater This use of *remember* isn't common anymore, but I don't think it's quite obsolete.  The problem I have is figuring out why the sentence switches to the past tense (*while we were in...*).  Seeing the full sentence might help, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

The usages are indeed different.

> With many thanks for your kind letter, and with a request that you remember me to your old colleagues. . .
>
> With many thanks for your kind letter, and with a request that you remember me to your old colleagues *while we were in ...*

The first construction here is entirely correct. "Remember me to them" [is an old expression](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21354/what-is-the-origin-and-use-of-remember-me-to-her-him) which roughly means "give them my greetings", or less formally "tell them I said hello".

The second one, which you said is the source, is puzzling. It basically works out to "tell them I said hello while we were in. . ." In what? It may be correct, but purely from the given context it's difficult to tell.

> With many thanks for your kind letter, and with a request that you remind me to your old colleagues while we were in ...

Regardless of the context, this is incorrect, or very seldom used. "Remind me to them" does show up in web searches as an alternate form of "remember me to them", but that's about it. "Remind them of me" or "remind them about me" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the posted questions are OK, but I don't think I have heard it this way in the US.
More likely, I would say it like this:

> With many thanks for your kind letter, and with a request that you **remind** your old colleagues **about me** . . .